# How to get web scraped data from Python/Beautiful Soup into a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, beautifulsoup

Although I am getting over 10 items as results in Python, right now I am only able to get the last product to appear in my MySQL database (with an id of 12 along with its information like price, picture, etc). I need to fix it so that they all appear and not just one product.

Python code is below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mysql.connector

url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20card'

source = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')



conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='x', database='scrape',password="x")                         
cursor = conn.cursor()  



item_container = soup.find_all('div', class_='item-container')


def get_data():
lists = []
    for index, item_name in enumerate(item_container):
        name = item_name.find_all('a', class_='item-title')[0].text
        lists.append({'name': name})
        lists[index]['index'] = index


    for index, item_price in enumerate(item_container):
        price = item_price.find('li', class_='price-current').find('strong')
        if price == None:

            price == ('Not Available')
            lists[index]['price'] = price


        else:

            price = ('$' + price.text +'.99')
            prices = []
        lists[index]['price'] = price

    for index, item_picture in enumerate(item_container):
            picture = 'http:' + item_picture.find('img', class_='lazy-img')['data-src']

            lists[index]['picture'] = picture

    for index, item_shipping in enumerate(item_container):
            shipping = (item_shipping.find('li', class_='price-ship').text).strip()
            lists[index]['shipping'] = shipping


def create_table():

    val_index = lists[index]['index']
    val_name = lists[index]['name']
    val_picture = lists[index]['picture']
    val_price = lists[index]['price']
    val_shipping = lists[index]['shipping']


    add_item = ("INSERT INTO newegg "
                "(id, itemname, itempic, itemprice, itemshipping) "
                "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

    data_item = (val_index, val_name, val_picture, val_price, val_shipping)


    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM newegg ")
    conn.commit()
    cursor.execute(add_item, data_item)  
    conn.commit()

    cursor.close() 
    conn.close()                                                                  

create_table();
get_data()
```

Comment: Why do you do `DELETE FROM newegg`? I think you're just deleting previous entries before inserting the next one. This will leave you with just the last entry.

Comment: https://imgur.com/T70Htxy

Comment: When I get rid of the DELETE FROM newegg line and the line, I get this error when I run the code:

Comment: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 427, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '11' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: You're not looping over `index` in `create_table`, so you're just trying to insert the last value of `index` each time you call `create_table`. Put the `DELETE` at the beginning of the function call, and then remember to loop `for thing in lists:` inside the function.

Comment: Can you write out this loop for me? I'm not sure how to do it. Thanks!!

Comment: Sure, just a minute. I'll just write `create_table`, but you probably also want to fix the `price == ('Not Available')` line.

Answer (score 1):

So the main thing that needs fixing is `create_table()`. We don't want it to be deleting the database contents right before inserting an item. Also, we need to loop over all of the items in your `lists`. I would do that this way.

```
def create_table():
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM newegg ")
    conn.commit()

    for product in lists:
        val_index = product['index']
        val_name = product['name']
        val_picture = product['picture']
        val_price = product['price']
        val_shipping = product['shipping']


        add_item = ("INSERT INTO newegg "
                    "(id, itemname, itempic, itemprice, itemshipping) "
                    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

        data_item = (val_index, val_name, val_picture, val_price, val_shipping)

        cursor.execute(add_item, data_item)
        conn.commit()
```

Notice, `create_table()` also no longer closes the connection for you. I would recommend closing the connection in the same scope where you initialized it (in this case, the global scope). Function `create_table()` doesn't "own" the connection resource so it should not be allowed to destroy it. Though it would make perfect sense to both initialize and destroy the connection inside of the function.

Also, note that this will clear out your table every time you do the scraping. This might be fine, but if you want to change your `id`s over time, don't delete at the beginning, and get your `id` column to auto increment  or something.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!!